# Deploying Common Lisp Web Applications

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, lisp, common-lisp, hunchentoot

I am wondering how one goes about deploying a Common Lisp web application written in, say, Hunchentoot, Wookie, Woo, or even Clack.

That is, suppose I write an app that contains some files, packages, etc. Typically when I am working locally, I simply run a command in REPL that starts the server and then visit it using `localhost:8000` or something like that.

However, I am a bit puzzled as to what the process is for deploying an app to a production server like AWS EC2. In what form should I deploy the Lisp code? Are there different options? What happens if the server needs to be restarted or is experiencing problems?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I've figured something out lately by building self-contained executables for web apps and I wrote about it on [lisp-journey/web-dev](https://lisp-journey.gitlab.io/web-dev/#shipping) (shipping and deployment sections), as well as for the building part on the [Common Lisp Cookbook/scripting#for-web-apps](https://lispcookbook.github.io/cl-cookbook/scripting.html#for-web-apps).

I copy the interesting parts here, there's a bit more on each resource. Edits are welcome, primarily on those resources thanks !

**edit** july 2019: I contributed a page on the Cookbook: https://lispcookbook.github.io/cl-cookbook/web.html

**edit**: see also a list of tools and platforms that provide professional CL support: https://github.com/CodyReichert/awesome-cl#deployment

## (edited) How to run the web app as a script

I explain below how to build and run executables, but we can of course run the application as a script. In a lisp file, say `run.lisp`, ensure:

- to load your project's asd file: `(load "my-project.asd")`
- to load its dependencies: `(ql:quickload :my-project)`
- to call its main function: `(my-project:start)` (given `start` is an exported symbol, otherwise `::start`).

In doing so, the application starts and gives you back a Lisp REPL. You can interact with the running application. You can update it and even install new Quicklisp libraries as it runs.

## How to build a self-contained executable

See also https://github.com/CodyReichert/awesome-cl#interfaces-to-other-package-managers for bindings to Homebrew and Debian packages.

### With SBCL

How to build (self-contained) executables is implementation-specific (see
below Buildapp and Rowsell). With SBCL, as says
[its documentation](http://www.sbcl.org/manual/index.html#Function-sb_002dext_003asave_002dlisp_002dand_002ddie),
it is a matter of:

```lisp
(sb-ext:save-lisp-and-die #P"path/name-of-executable" :toplevel #'my-app:main-function :executable t)
```

`sb-ext` is an SBCL extension to run external processes.  See other
[SBCL extensions](http://www.sbcl.org/manual/index.html#Extensions)
(many of them are made implementation-portable in other libraries).

`:executable  t`  tells  to  build  an  executable  instead  of  an
image. We  could build an  image to save  the state of  our current
Lisp image, to come back working with it later. Specially useful if
we made a lot of work that is computing intensive.

If you try to run this in Slime, you'll get an error about threads running:

> Cannot save core with multiple threads running.

Run the command from a simple SBCL repl.

I suppose your project has Quicklisp dependencies. You must then:

- ensure Quicklisp is installed and loaded at Lisp startup (you
  completed Quicklisp installation)
- `load` the project's .asd
- install dependencies
- build the executable.

That gives:

```
(load "my-app.asd")
(ql:quickload :my-app)
(sb-ext:save-lisp-and-die #p"my-app-binary" :toplevel #'my-app:main :executable t)
```

From the command line, or from a Makefile, use `--load` and `--eval`:

```
build:
    sbcl --non-interactive \
         --load my-app.asd \
         --eval '(ql:quickload :my-app)' \
         --eval "(sb-ext:save-lisp-and-die #p\"my-app\" :toplevel #my-app:main :executable t)"
```

### With ASDF

Now that we'seen the basics, we need a portable method. Since its
version 3.1, ASDF allows to do that. It introduces the [`make` command](https://common-lisp.net/project/asdf/asdf.html#Convenience-Functions),
that reads parameters from the .asd. Add this to your .asd declaration:

```
:build-operation "program-op" ;; leave as is
:build-pathname "<binary-name>"
:entry-point "<my-system:main-function>"
```

and call `asdf:make :my-system`.

So, in a Makefile:

```
LISP ?= sbcl

build:
    $(LISP) --non-interactive \
        --load my-app.asd \
        --eval '(ql:quickload :my-app)' \
        --eval '(asdf:make :my-system)'
```

### With Roswell or Buildapp

[Roswell](https://roswell.github.io), an implementation manager and much
more, also has the `ros build` command, that should work for many
implementations.

We can also make our app installable with Roswell by a `ros install my-app`. See its documentation.

We'll finish with a word on
[Buildapp](http://www.xach.com/lisp/buildapp/), a battle-tested and
still popular "application for SBCL or CCL that configures and saves
an executable Common Lisp image".

Many applications use it (for example,
[pgloader](https://github.com/dimitri/pgloader)),  it is available on
Debian: `apt install buildapp`, but you shouldn't need it now with asdf:make or Roswell.

### For web apps

We can similarly build a self-contained executable for our web-app. It
would thus contain a web server and would be able to run on the
command line:

```
$ ./my-web-app
Hunchentoot server is started.
Listening on localhost:9003.
```

Note that this runs the production webserver, not a development one,
so we can run the binary on our VPS right away and access the app from
outside.

We have one thing to take care of, it is to find and put the thread of
the running web server on the foreground. In our `main` function, we
can do something like this:

```
(defun main ()
  (start-app :port 9003) ;; our start-app, for example clack:clack-up
  ;; let the webserver run.
  ;; warning: hardcoded "hunchentoot".
  (handler-case (bt:join-thread (find-if (lambda (th)
                                            (search "hunchentoot" (bt:thread-name th)))
                                         (bt:all-threads)))
    ;; Catch a user's C-c
    (#+sbcl sb-sys:interactive-interrupt
      #+ccl  ccl:interrupt-signal-condition
      #+clisp system::simple-interrupt-condition
      #+ecl ext:interactive-interrupt
      #+allegro excl:interrupt-signal
      () (progn
           (format *error-output* "Aborting.~&")
           (clack:stop *server*)
           (uiop:quit)))
    (error (c) (format t "Woops, an unknown error occured:~&~a~&" c))))
```

We used the `bordeaux-threads` library (`(ql:quickload "bordeaux-threads")`, alias `bt`) and `uiop`, which is part of ASDF so
already loaded, in order to exit in a portable way (`uiop:quit`, with
an optional return code, instead of `sb-ext:quit`).

## Parsing command line arguments

see the Cookbook [here](https://lispcookbook.github.io/cl-cookbook/scripting.html). TLDR; use `uiop:command-line-arguments` to get a list of the arguments. To parse them for real, there are libraries.

## Deployment

Straightforward with an executable. The web app is visible from the outside right away.

#### On Heroku

See [this buildpack](https://gitlab.com/duncan-bayne/heroku-buildpack-common-lisp).

#### Daemonizing, restarting in case of crashes, handling logs

See how to do that on your system.

Most GNU/Linux distros now come with Systemd.

Examples [search](https://lmddgtfy.net/?q=systemd%20daemonize%20application) result:

- https://seanmcgary.com/posts/deploying-nodejs-applications-with-systemd/

It is as simple as writing a configuration file:

```
# /etc/systemd/system/my-app.service
[Unit]
Description=stupid simple example

[Service]
WorkingDirectory=/path/to/your/app
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/sthg sthg
Type=simple
Restart=always
RestartSec=10
```

running a command to start it:

```
sudo systemctl start my-app.service
```

a command to check its status:

```
systemctl status my-app.service
```

and Systemd can handle **logging** (we write to stdout or stderr, it writes logs):

```
journalctl -f -u my-app.service
```

and it handles crashes and **restarts the app**:

```
Restart=always
```

and it can **start the app after a reboot**:

```
[Install]
WantedBy=basic.target
```

to enable it:

```
sudo systemctl enable my-app.service
```

#### Debugging SBCL error: ensure_space: failed to allocate n bytes

If you get this error with SBCL on your server:

```
mmap: wanted 1040384 bytes at 0x20000000, actually mapped at 0x715fa2145000
ensure_space: failed to allocate 1040384 bytes at 0x20000000
(hint: Try "ulimit -a"; maybe you should increase memory limits.)
```

then disable [ASLR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization):

```
sudo bash -c "echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/randomize_va_space"
```

### Connecting to a remote Swank server

Little example here: http://cvberry.com/tech_writings/howtos/remotely_modifying_a_running_program_using_swank.html.

Demo project here: https://lisp-journey.gitlab.io/blog/i-realized-that-to-live-reload-my-web-app-is-easy-and-convenient/

It defines a simple function that prints forever:

```
;; a little common lisp swank demo
;; while this program is running, you can connect to it from another terminal or machine
;; and change the definition of doprint to print something else out!
;; (ql:quickload :swank)
;; (ql:quickload :bordeaux-threads)

(require :swank)
(require :bordeaux-threads)

(defparameter *counter* 0)

(defun dostuff ()
  (format t "hello world ~a!~%" *counter*))

(defun runner ()
  (bt:make-thread (lambda ()
                    (swank:create-server :port 4006)))
  (format t "we are past go!~%")
  (loop while t do
       (sleep 5)
       (dostuff)
       (incf *counter*)
       ))

(runner)
```

On our server, we run it with

```
sbcl --load demo.lisp
```

we do port forwarding on our development machine:

```
ssh -L4006:127.0.0.1:4006 username@example.com
```

this will securely forward port 4006 on the server at example.com to
our local computer's port 4006 (swanks accepts connections from
localhost).

We connect to the running swank with `M-x slime-connect`, typing in
port 4006.

We can write new code:

```
(defun dostuff ()
  (format t "goodbye world ~a!~%" *counter*))
(setf *counter* 0)
```

and eval it as usual with `M-x slime-eval-region` for instance. The output should change.

There are more pointers on CV Berry's page.

### Hot reload

Example with [Quickutil](https://github.com/tarballs-are-good/quickutil/blob/master/quickutil-server/). See notes on lisp-journey.

It has to be run on the server (a simple fabfile command can call this
through ssh). Beforehand, a `fab update` has run `git pull` on the
server, so new code is present but not running. It connects to the
local swank server, loads the new code, stops and starts the app in a
row.

## Continuous Integration, continuous delivery of executables, Docker

See https://lispcookbook.github.io/cl-cookbook/testing.html#continuous-integration

Comment: When you write `asdf:make :my-package`, I'd have expected `asdf:make :my-system` instead, because even though systems and packages are often named the same, this is not necessarily the case and it could bring confusion. Other than that, great answer!

Comment: Thanks mate! You Lisp answers are great, as always! By the way, are you Eitaro Fukamachi? If so, just wanted to tell you that your activity in the Lisp community is really impressive :)

Comment: @coredump Good point, thank you ! MadPhysicist: Thanks ! Wow I appreciate you take me for E. Fukamachi^^ I wish I was but no, I'm far from being as gifted and productive ! I'm the author of those two pages I linked to so you can see, my github nickname is vindarel.

Comment: @Ehvince I have a couple of questions. Are you the one writing this? https://lisp-journey.gitlab.io/ It is very helpful to me as someone relatively new to CL. In fact, I have started doing something similar on my own site as it helps me retain the material and save notes for the future. 

The other question is whether you would suggest some material about debugging, tracing and other similar topics when it comes to CL? In short, if I need to understand how certain code works by looking through some values in those functions and stepping through them, how do I do it?

Comment: Yes that's my lisp journey, I did unashamed self-promotion in my answer but I'm very glad it's helpful for newcomers: I have that in mind, since I am too. Yeah we need such a chapter on the cookbook, I'm gathering notes. No much space here. See [malisper posts](http://malisper.me/category/debugging-common-lisp/), don't forget `(declaim`. [break example](https://www.reddit.com/r/learnlisp/comments/7lgpjw/need_help_with_basic_debug_skills_in_common_lisp/), and log4cl. See `trace`, `step`, `defadvice`etc, big chapter in "Successful lisp" by David B. Lamkins. Open an issue in the Cookbook !

Comment: @MadPhysicist and the best solution of all *seems* to be (couldn't try yet) [Sly's stickers](https://joaotavora.github.io/sly/#Stickers), exactly what you ask.

Comment: Sounds good. I have been meaning to start contributing to it!

Comment: Do you know if there is a version of these SLY Stickers that works for SLIME?

Comment: Yep, and no, it's a Sly killer feature.

Answer (score 6):

To run a lisp image in production, you can generate a fasl file from your lisp code with:

```
(compile-file "app.lisp")
```

run your generated .fas file by invoking sbcl.

```
sbcl --noinform \
     --load app.fas \
     --eval "(defun main (argv) (declare (ignore argv)) (hunchentoot:start (make-instance 'hunchentoot:easy-acceptor :port 4242)))"
```

Comment: that makes no real difference for evaluation vs. compilation, since SBCL could just as good use the source file and compile it on the fly. It reduces the load time to load the fasl file, since the code is already compiled. But invoking SBCL that way is one way to start a Lisp and have it execute some code.

Comment: If I take the app to production this way, would I be able to connect to it remotely and make changes to code in the form of the so-called "hot swap?"

Comment: For that, you'd best also start a swank server in your image.

Answer (score 5):

I found a blog with a solution that I have adapted to my needs for a production system on a linux box. Unfortunately I cannot find the reference to that blog anymore, so that I can just show you my solution, which is for CCL (while the original solution was for SBCL), which with I am more familiar. Here is the program that starts the system:

```
(require 'swank)
(require 'hunchentoot)

(defparameter *httpd-port* 9090)     ; The port Hunchentoot will be listening on
(defparameter *shutdown-port* 6700)  ; The port CCL will be listening for shutdown
                                     ; this port is the same used in /etc/init.d/hunchentoot
(defparameter *swank-port* 5016)     ; The port used for remote interaction with slime

;; Start the Swank server
(defparameter *swank-server*
  (swank:create-server :port *swank-port* :dont-close t))

(require 'YOUR-PACKAGE)
(YOUR-PACKAGE:YOUR-STARTING-FUNCTION)

(princ "Hunchentoot started on port ")
(princ *httpd-port*)
(terpri)

(let* ((socket (make-socket :connect :passive :local-host "127.0.0.1" :local-port *shutdown-port* :reuse-address t))
       (stream (accept-connection socket)))
  (close stream)
  (close socket))

(print "Stopping Hunchentoot...")
(YOUR-PACKAGE:YOUR-STOPPING-FUNCTION)

(dolist (proc (all-processes))
  (unless (equal proc *current-process*)
    (process-kill proc)))
(sleep 1)
(quit)
```

The idea is that you can connect to the running system with slime, by specifying the port used by swank. I used it a couple of times, for instance to change a database link on the fly, and was quite impressed by the power of such possibility.

The running system can be terminated by:

```
telnet 127.0.0.1 6700
```

and initiated by something like:

```
nohup ccl -l initcclserver.lisp >& server.out &
```

In a previous version of the script I found the SBCL-specific parts, so if you use it you could modify the script.

For accepting the terminating connections:

```
(sb-bsd-sockets:socket-bind socket #(127 0 0 1) *shutdown-port*)
(sb-bsd-sockets:socket-listen socket 1)
(multiple-value-bind (client-socket addr port)
  (sb-bsd-sockets:socket-accept socket)
(sb-bsd-sockets:socket-close client-socket)
(sb-bsd-sockets:socket-close socket)))
```

To close the system:

```
(dolist (thread (sb-thread:list-all-threads))
  (unless (equal sb-thread:*current-thread* thread)
    (sb-thread:terminate-thread thread)))
(sleep 1)
(sb-ext:quit)
```

Hope this can help.