How to deploy a web application so that I can modify its code, while it is running?
Let's say there is a web application running on a VPS with Linux as a systemd service, or whatever is best for it. Is it possible to access the running Lisp image with a new REPL instance or somehow reopen the one, that was used as entry point to the application?
I imagine having a run.lisp fie, executed by systemd, having the following code:
(ql:quickload <system-dependencies>)
(asdf:load-asd "system-name.asd")
(ql:quickload :system-name)
(main)

Where main function would run, let's say, hunchentoot with bordeaux threads.
I would assume there is a way to bring a background process to foreground, open a running REPL and redefine an existing function. And then I would have to also modify a file, containing the original function definition, so that changes are kept on reboot.
The last thing I want to do is to shut down the web application and restart it. I could code a gracefull exit process, so that all important tasks are finished and the progress is saved by the time the app dies. It's an option, but it's it really, given that Lisp is all about REPL?

related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48103501/deploying-common-lisp-web-applications

When we did this (a fairly long time ago now) we made two observations which drove how we did it:

we never wanted to be in a situation where someone, whoever that was, was typing random untested crap at the live application;
in any case in order to deploy a patch into the live system it had to go through a suitable little dance to make sure things were sane.

So we did three things:

You could run the application in development mode which just meant running it from the REPL as you would expect.  In that mode you could dynamically change things without fear (sometimes with bad results).  Once you had sorted it all out the patch would end up being a little FASL file containing (compiled code for) forms which the application knew what to do with.  Patches had names, versions and dependencies.
These patches once ready to go could be tested in development mode in a clean image (and in principle in a test-environment live application, but we never did that).
Once all ready you installed the FASL or FASLs in a standard place and sent the live system a signal (might have been SIGHUP).  There was a handler for this which kicked off the 'check for new patches, get the system into a good state to load them, load them' sequence.

When the application was started from cold it would run this same process during startup.  It only loaded patches it needed (so if there were patch files which were older than the initial image version they did not get loaded).

You have 2 options:

run your app in tmux and use the default REPL
run your app with Systemd or another service, start a Swank server and connect to it from home (requires more setup, but the method I recommend)

NB: I had gathered notes: on the Cookbook: https://lispcookbook.github.io/cl-cookbook/debugging.html#remote-debugging and on this answer: Deploying Common Lisp Web Applications
tmux
If you run your web app on the CLI, start the web server and leave it on its background thread (the default), then you get a regular CL REPL on the terminal after your app has started:
[loading…]
started my-app on port 8000…
CL-USER> 

you can do whatever you want on the REPL, you can edit files and (load …) them on the REPL.
You can detach the tmux session and re-attach it later.
I don't know of canonical ways to handle crashes and restart the app on a server restart, which is what brings us to Systemd.
Systemd
With Systemd you might want to bring the web server thread to the foreground (with join-thread, see linked SO answer) and then sleep for most-positive-fixnum.
With Systemd we don't have access to the Lisp REPL, so we'll want to start a Swank server and connect to it.
;; quickload "swank"
(swank-loader:init :load-contribs t)
(swank:create-server :port swank-port :dont-close t)

:dont-close t is important for long-running processes.
then we connect to it from the outside with an SSH port forwarding:
ssh -L4006:127.0.0.1:4006 username@example.com
# => on success this opens a shell on the server

(see the Cookbook for details)
then we connect to the running image with M-x slime-connect, choosing "localhost" and the Swank port.
trivia: That’s how Ron Garret debugged the Deep Space 1 spacecraft from Earth in 1999.
last notes

I would assume there is a way to bring a background process to foreground

this is not necessary by using a Swank server.

open a running REPL and redefine an existing function. And then I would have to also modify a file, containing the original function definition, so that changes are kept on reboot.

To avoid this mismatch, you first connect, open the file locally at home, make the changes and compile them while being connected to the running image / send them to the REPL. You're connected, but you edit files locally.
As a consequence, your files on the server are not synced yet, but you write changes to files.
References

https://common-lisp.net/project/slime/doc/html/Connecting-to-a-remote-lisp.html#Connecting-to-a-remote-lisp

See more

https://github.com/vindarel/demo-web-live-reload -> stating the obvious, how using the default terminal REPL allows to live-reload a running web app. (this is what we would do in tmux)
https://lisp-journey.gitlab.io/blog/lisp-for-the-web-build-standalone-binaries-foreign-libraries-templates-static-assets/ -> it is possible to build self-contained websites, with templates and static assets. Explanations with Djula (.html) templates.

NB: if you have custom slime extensions in your init.el, connecting might fail.

Yes.  I've seen web services that ran for years in a setup like this.   CL-daemonize, detach-tty may be of interest.  Leaving the slime listener open is useful.  As is Emacs tramp along with a bit of port forwarding.  The laundry list of things to work though is large, but no longer than any other long running upgradable software system.  What Common Lisp brings to he party is that you can modify the running system to an amazingly extent.
